# How to find slant asymptote with exponential variable

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I was asked to graph the function $f(x) = 2x + e^{-x}$. I was unable to tell that there is a slant asymptote at $y = 2x$, and my teacher did not give an explanation of that. How does one find the slant asymptotes for functions with exponential variables?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2x+e^{-x}>2x$ for all x,  for x to $ \infty$  $e^{-x}->0$ so $f(x)->2x $
you can see that for example $x=10:  f(10)=2*10+0.000045$ so very close.